# problem when running spring boot application : error 864

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make a very simple spring boot java program and here is all my data file.

At first, I created a file named UserRepository.java, here it is

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType; 
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String lastName;
private String email;
public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

As you can see, in this file, I create three elements, firstName, lastName, email for the User
And here is the User.java file

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String lastName;
private String email;
public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Here is the UserController.java file

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.User;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.UserRepository;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@GetMapping("users")
public List<User> getUsers() {
return this.userRepository.findAll();       
}
}
```

And here is the Thinghiem1Application.java file

```
package net.javaguides.springboot;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.User;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.UserRepository;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Thinghiem1Application implements CommandLineRunner{
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(Thinghiem1Application.class, args);
}
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.userRepository.save(new User("Duc", "Nguyen", "ramesh@gmail.com"));
    this.userRepository.save(new User("Long", "Hoang", "tom@gmail.com"));
    this.userRepository.save(new User("Tony", "Lan", "dir@gmail.com"));
}
}
```

When I wrote the java file, there was no error, but when I ran the java file as Spring Boot App, it said to me this ERROR :

```
2021-07-15 18:52:27.051 ERROR 864 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: net.javaguides.springboot.model.User column: first_name (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Could you please give me some ideas with this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The error exactly tells you what is wrong... You sloppy/pasted the `@Column(name="first_name")` to your `lastName` field. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your `User.java` class, you've mapped both of the variables `firstName` and `lastName` to the database column `first_name` which is wrong.
Change the `@Column(name = "first_name")` of variable `lastName` to `@Column(name = "last_name")` and your issue will be solved.

**Sweet Note:** Copy pasting lines may cause silly but hard to find bugs, try avoid copying lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping `first_name to field last_name`:

```java
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String lastName;
```

It should be something like:

```java
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: net.javaguides.springboot.model.User column: first_name
```

If you read the Exception you will notice `Repeated column` and `User column: first_name`

In your class you by mistike you you used the `first_name` twice in `@Column`

```
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String lastName;
```

Just change the `lastName` `@Column` annotation value to "last_name"

Answer (score 0):

**Repeated column in mapping for entity: net.javaguides.springboot.model.User column: first_name**

Reason- @Column(name = "first_name") it will map your entity class field (firstName) into Database  as column **first_name** this happens via Object relational mapping ([ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping))

As your entity field, firstName and lastName bot have the same ORM @Column(name = "first_name") that is why you are getting **Repeated column in mapping** Error